# Ract JS: React JS modal appearing W/O CSS

Tags: reactjs, react-css-modules, react-modal

I am new to ReactJS, React modal appearing without css.

I have attached the screen shot for it

[image]

Below is the code for modal I am using

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import  {Modal, Button} from 'react-bootstrap'

    render(){
        return (
            <Modal
            {...this.props}
            size="lg"
            aria-labelledby="contained-modal-title-vcenter"
            centered
          >
            <Modal.Header closeButton>
              <Modal.Title id="contained-modal-title-vcenter">
                Modal heading
              </Modal.Title>
            </Modal.Header>
            <Modal.Body>

            <label>
              AGE:
              <input type="text" name="age" ref={this.props.setref1}/>
            </label>
            </Modal.Body>
            <Modal.Footer>
              <Button onClick={this.props.getdetails}>SUBMIT</Button>
            </Modal.Footer>
          </Modal>
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you import the css of react-bootstrap?

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
```

Answer (score 0):

If you read the documentation carefully you will see this one: [Stylesheets section](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/getting-started/introduction#stylesheets).

So you either need to add `import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';` `src/index.js` or `App.js` file

or add

```
<link
  rel="stylesheet"
  href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
  integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T"
  crossorigin="anonymous"
/>
```

in index.html

Answer (score 0):

React-Bootstrap doesn't depend on a very precise version of Bootstrap, and don't ship with any included css. However, some stylesheet is required to use these components.

check this : https://react-bootstrap.github.io/getting-started/introduction

Or add this :

```
<link
  rel="stylesheet"
  href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
  integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T"
  crossorigin="anonymous"
/>
```